# Download file through WebApi returns JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I'm using Visual Studio 2019, WebApi project, .NET Core 3.1

My endpoint looks like this:

```
    [HttpGet("GetFile")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetFile([FromQuery] string filePath)
    {
        var bytes = await System.IO.File.ReadAllBytesAsync(filePath).ConfigureAwait(false);

        using var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes),
        };

        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition =
            new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath),
            };

        result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
            new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

        return result;
    }
```

When I got to URL, it returns serialized HttpResponseMessage in JSON. 
How can I download file from endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify, you can just use something like:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetFile([FromQuery] string filePath)
{
   var bytes = await System.IO.File.ReadAllBytesAsync(filePath).ConfigureAwait(false);
   return File(bytes, "application/octet-stream", Path.GetFileName(filePath));
}
```